# Can you navigate from one LWC to another?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I can't find anything that would allow me to navigate from one LWC to another.  I have a search LWC that returns a list.  From a record returned in the list, I want to open a LWC for that record and pass the ID.

Thanks!!

Fred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer by sfdcfox this is currently not possible and you can follow the suggestion provided.

Another way to get navigation will be to use LWC component wrapped in Aura components.
You can create an Aura component which holds the LWC component. Whenever there is a navigation requirement just dispatch the custom event back to the Aura component. In the aura component handle the event from LWC and navigate to a different Aura component which has another LWC component.

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently do this. LWC does not support URL-addressable navigation, so you can't navigate to them at this time. I expect this will likely be available in the future, although we don't have a timeline for this yet. For now, you would build a top-level LWC component to handle displaying one or the other based on the current state.